# Removing special character SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have column in a table which contains special characters with an attached string. The same column contains numbers also. I am only intresed in extracting numbers out of that column e.g

```
Name-3445 => 3445; Out-90 => 90; 786  => 786
```

How would i do this in SQL or PL/SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(some_column, '[^0-9]*', '') as clean_value
FROM your_table
```

Comment: It should be be `'[^0-9]+'` not `*`

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL has a REGEX_REPLACE function, which you could use to replace anything that isn't a digit with an empty string.  Details on REGEX_REPLACE can be found here: http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the integrity of your data, something like this might do what you're asking:

```
select CAST(SUBSTRING(_COLUMNNAME_,CHARINDEX('-', _COLUMNNAME_),1000), Integer) as ColumnName
from tblTable where _COLUMNNAME_ like '%-%'
union all select CAST(_COLUMNNAME, Integer) as ColumnName
from tblTable where _COLUMNNAME_ not like '%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regexp_substr function:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(<Your_String>,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']', NULL)
```

Example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('##$$$123&&!!__!','[^[:alnum:]'' '']', NULL) FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
123
```